# Near by search in google maps using latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-maps

I'm developing website where all take away restaurants are register. I also have given facility to restaurants to mark their location on google map and their latitude and longitude are saved in database.

I need to search restaurants in 25km radius. I also have users latitude and longitude saved in database.

In short my requirement is I need to show all restaurants in 25km radius from users location.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I can recommend you this code.

```
SELECT id, 
( 6371 * 
    ACOS( 
        COS( RADIANS( db_latitude ) ) * 
        COS( RADIANS( $user_latitude ) ) * 
        COS( RADIANS( $user_longitude ) - 
        RADIANS( db_longitude ) ) + 
        SIN( RADIANS( db_latitude ) ) * 
        SIN( RADIANS( $user_latitude) ) 
    ) 
) 
AS distance FROM the_table HAVING distance <= $the_radius ORDER BY distance ASC"
```

You can just do it in sql query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database with a spatial index for example MySQL. You can also use a quadkey. You can download my php class hilbert-curve @ phpclasses.org. It uses a quadkey and a mercator projection.

Comment: can you please, tell me in detail.

Comment: A quadkey recursively subdivide the surface. It's similar to a quadtree. When you search for restaurant you need only to search nearby locations.